# Cannot force logout in ASP.NET Identity

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-identity, owin

Although I tried some of the following methods in LogOff method, the user can login by using "Back" button of the browser after logout from the system. What is the smartest way to force logout in ASP.NET MVC with ASP.NET Identity?

```
public ActionResult LogOff()
{
    AuthenticationManager.SignOut();

    //I added these lines extra in order to force logout
    FormsAuthentication.SignOut(); 
    Session.Clear();
    Session.Abandon();
    Session.RemoveAll();
    //

    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to disable your cache for whole project. This is very **bad programming**. Not recommended at all.

Keep this bellow code inside `Application_BeginRequest()` of `Global.asax` file.

```
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(-1));
Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
```

Or-else you can clean your cache by using java script to prevent **Back button**, like bellow,

```
<script>
function ClearHistory()
 {
  var backlen = history.length;
  history.go(-backlen);
  window.location.href = loggedOutPageUrl //Pass your Index Page
 }
</script>
```

Please go through this [link](https://www.codeproject.com/tips/135121/browser-back-button-issue-after-logout.aspx), there are many ways to **prevent back button** using java script.

Hope it helps.

Comment: The first method did not worked. For the second method, shall I call it in Logout button?

Comment: What happen with the first method ? You need to change the Hours value ? Yes, you need to call the 2nd method in your logout button.

Comment: It does not make any sense when using the first method. I would prefer to use an approach as in first method. Any idea? (Voted+ for your help...)

Comment: Can you add this line in first method and check once. Response.Cache.VaryByParams.IgnoreParams = true;

Comment: Unfortunately not working. I think maybe it is almost impossible without using Javascript.

Comment: Thanks, but as you said it is not a good idea that also affects another part of the programme.

Comment: Right. I have mentioned 1 URL, Check once, there are many ways to prevent back button using java script

Answer (score 0):

`AuthenticationManager.SignOut()` needs to be called with a parameter, depending on how you logged in your users. Usually this will work to cover all cases:

```
AuthenticationManager.SignOut(
    DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie,
    DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
    DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorCookie,
    DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie,
    DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalBearer);
```

No need to do `FormsAuthentication.SignOut()` - this will not do anything. No need to abandon session either, unless you have used it yourself - Identity does not put anything into a Session.

Comment: Thanks, I tried to use this approach but does not work neither. It is very strange, I cleared all of the history and cookies of the browser and then login to the system. Then logout and press Back button of the browser and easily returned to the previous page that requires login to the system. Any other idea?

Comment: But on the previous page, if you refresh the page, does it not require you to login?

Comment: Yes, exactly... In that case that is the only solution without Javascript?

Comment: JS is nothing to do with this. If somebody logged out - their cookie is gone. Even if the browser shows the previous page - they can't do anything with it, as any new action requires a cookie and it is gone. Being able to click "back" is a browser "feature" and depends on a browser used. Just ignore it.

Comment: I tested with using only **AuthenticationManager.SignOut()** (without any parameter) and it behaves the same. After pressing Back and going the previous page I clicked an action but it redirects teh Login page. So, there seems to be no difference between using this method with or without parameters. Any idea?

Comment: So it logs you out anyway then? so there is no problem then?

Comment: Seems to be ok, but in some pages made with ASP.NET MVC, there is not such a situation and when pressing Back and Forward, the page goes to Login instead of previous page that seems to be much more better.